# Destructure a `dict` of length one to assign its key and value to two variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of `dict`ionaries with only one key-value pairs that are sometimes generated by one of the scripts I wrote, and I need to get rid of them.

To do this, I need to get the key and value of the `dict`. Minimal reproducible example to illustrate my intent:

```py
d = {'a': 0}
assert len(d) == 1
k, v = list(d.items())[0]
```

Don't know if this is a duplicate, but I can't find an answer using Google.

Is there a simpler way to get `k, v` from `d`?

---

### Edit

In case anyone's wondering, here is where the situation arises:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def recur_dir(path, root=''):
    first = False
    if not root:
        assert Path(path).is_dir()
        root = path
        first = True
    report = {'folders': dict(), 'files': []}
    for element in Path(path).iterdir():
        if element.is_file():
            report['files'].append(element.name)
        elif element.is_dir():
           report['folders'].update(recur_dir(str(element).replace('\\', '/'), root))
    
    folders = report['folders']
    for name, folder in list(folders.items()):
        if not folder:
            folders.pop(name)
        if not folder.get('files', None):
            folders[name].pop('files', None)
            if len(folder['folders']) == 1:
                key, value = folder['folders'].popitem()
                folders[key] = value
                folders.pop(name)
        elif not folder['folders']:
            folders[name].pop('folders')
    
    if not report.get('files', None):
        report.pop('files', None)
    
    if first:
        return {path: report}
    else:
        return {path.replace(root, ''): report}
```

In short, I wrote a script that recursively lists the contents of any given directory, and some sub-directories are empty, other sub-directories may contain one sub-directory and nothing else.

I want to remove the empty sub-directories and join the names of sub-directories that contain only one sub-directory to remove unnecessary nesting levels.

This question is related to the second part, I have not yet figured out a way not to create unnecessary nesting levels in the first place...

Comment: *"generated by one of the scripts I wrote, and I need to get rid of them."* - Hmm, actually... How about not generating them in the first place then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the dict anymore (as your *"get rid of them"* suggests):

```
k, v = d.popitem()
```

If you do:

```
(k, v), = d.items()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/P0XBVqFaPVHdSsGgliuxuDi1qEQhJzVPI0VTwdZWwZArW0ehDKgkJ7O4RCNFL7MkNbdYQ1Mz2iCWq6AoM69EAySvycUFoXWAKuGKUBVAzUnRK8gvAClAlf//HwA)

Comment: Could it be done with list comprehension directly? I tried `k, v = [i], [j] for i in d.values()` but I don't get the correct syntax to unpack values

Comment: @Cardstdani List comprehensions are for creating lists. They don't want to create lists. (At least as far as I can see. Maybe their actual use case with a "bunch" of dictionaries wants a list, but they haven't shown that.)

Comment: @Cardstdani Btw not sure what you're trying there. Are you trying to build two lists with one comprehension? Oh and another way, but I don't like it much: `k, v = *d, *d.values()`.